# Injecting someone into a Journey from Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are looking at using Data Stream data from Salesforce to inject people into a Journey via the Saleforce Events. My understanding is the Salesforce Events are triggered off of a record insert or update.

Is there an alternative way to inject someone into a Journey if this data already exists? So the field on the object we are using will already be populated so an insert and/or update won't happen.

Comment: Is it just a one time injection? When you say field is already populated, what will happen in future?

Comment: There can be multiple ways to handle this.. Can toh explain your requirement a little bit more ?

Comment: My thought was a one time injection of already existing data, then inserts would inject them from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to achieve that. What you can do is create develop an apex class which updates all the records in that Salesforce object. That will inject all he records in the journey for the first time.

Comment: Thank you. That was our initial thought, but was wondering if there were alternatives or built in methods that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your synchronized data extensions to the objects you need from Salesforce, you could create an automation that queries this data every hour and injects them into your event.